# Unable to view the title/InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a Google Map implemented,with some styling. But when I click on the marker the InfoView is not displlayed I suppose it is because of the Styling as I have another div infront of it like so

```
<div id="map">  </div>
<div id="background"></div>
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#background{
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, transparent 20%, #0e1626 60%, #0e1626 100%);
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to overcome this?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4m03Lth/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to `#background` to make it not receive hover/click events, so that you can hover and click whatever is behind it, i.e. the map marker.

The browser support of `pointer-events: none;` is good: https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m2x8j2hn/

Comment: But this still has a problem when the pointer is at the edge,the infoView is little visible. I am trying to find a way of putting Z-index to the marker which will be useful in this scenerio

Comment: Could you describe your new problem more? I'm not sure what you are meaning.